# How can I manually create a bookmark in Forefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I need to bookmark a link to our AWS console login page, however, everytime I enter the URL into the address bar, it morphs into something else.  And if I bookmark that something else, it doesn't work.  AWS knows this and says to manually create a bookmark, but how do I do that in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Click the Show Bookmarks icon (kind of like a clipboard) to the right of the Bookmark icon (star) in the upper right of the Firefox window.  At the bottom of the resulting popup window click on the Show All Boorkmarks link to get to the Library window.

Alternatively, the keyboard shortcut of Ctl + Shift + B will open the Firefox Library window directly.

In any case, choose where in the Bookmark tree on the left where you want to place your new bookmark, right click and select New Bookmark from the popup menu.  The New Bookmark dialog will open, with the Name defaulting to New Bookmark, change that to whatever you want and paste the url into the Location box.  You can also add tags, keywords and a description if you choose to do so.  Then click ok and your new bookmark should work.

Comment: This is outdated

Answer (score 0):

Now it is `CTRL+SHIFT+O` that opens the bookmark library

Go to the folder you want to add your bookmark then right click
and choose `add bookmark`